# C# File Upload via POST REST API in a Self-Hosted Web Server Environment

Tags: c#, rest, post, file-upload, self-hosting

I have a Web Service I've created that is self-hosted using "HttpSelfHostConfiguration" from "System.Web.Http.SelfHost". I need to create a REST API that allows others to make a POST call to upload a file to my service.

All of the research I've done so far has been for hosted Web Services, like in IIS. So what that allows them to do is use "HttpContext.Current" to get the HttpRequest content.

However, in self-hosted environments, "HttpContext.Current" is null, so I need to go an alternate route. My Google-fu may be off, but I can't seem to find any information with how to accomplish this in a self-hosted environment.

Does anyone have any examples or advice on how to accomplish creating a REST API that allows people to POST files to in this situation?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use HttpRequestMessage like below in your post method

> ```
> public HttpResponseMessage Post(HttpRequestMessage request) {...}
> ```

Then you can use some thing like below to extract the context of the request message

> string sRequestcXMLContent =
>   Encoding.UTF8.GetString(request.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result);

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Hi, Darshana!

I tried out the code above. Debugging my service, I am definitely getting the right function to be called by my REST API client calling a POST on my Web Server.

However, with that setup above, "Post(HttpRequestMessage request)", it seems like the "request.Content" I get in the "request" variable is empty (request.Content.Headers.ContentLength is 0). Now, maybe my client is messed up (I'll be doing some tests to make sure it's not), but in case you might know the issue right away, I figured I'd give you an update on my situation now.

Comment: Just FYI, tried another client and I wasn't getting content lengths of 0 anymore. I'll keep experimenting and update you again!

Comment: Sorry it's taken me a while to get back to you! It worked great and then I got distracted coding stuff for a couple of days. ^_^ But thanks again so much! It was a huge help!

Answer (score 1):

this post helped me allot but i thought i'd post my solution to help people.

```
    public async void Post(HttpRequestMessage Message)
    {
        MultipartMemoryStreamProvider x = await Message.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();
        Byte[] xx = await x.Contents[0].ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
        File.WriteAllBytes("c:\\test.png", xx);
    }
```